# change the color of cells that contain "-" to yellow in a Student Grades Table in html

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

Basically learned js in the last 3 hours, so I apologize if there are any mistakes, but basically "-" is used to indicate that an assignment has not been submitted and in those cells, I need to turn them yellow just to indicate that, I think. Here is my javaScript function to calculate the average of those grades, if anyone could help it'd be greatly appreciated. Also if anyone could help with the efficiency of this code and some helpful links to learn js. Thanks very much!

```
     getAverageFunction = function()
     {

        var Table = document.getElementById('gradesTable');
        var rowLength =Table.rows.length;

       for(var i =1; i<rowLength; i++)
        {
          var cellsInTable = Table.rows.item(i).cells;
          var sum = 0;


           for(var j =2; j< cellsInTable.length-1; j++)
            {
               var valueCell = cellsInTable.item(j).innerHTML;

               var currentValue = parseInt(valueCell);


               if(currentValue >= 0 && currentValue <=100)
                   `enter code here`{
        sum += currentValue; 

      }
            //trying to turn cells that contain '-' yellow
         if(cellsInTable.value === '-')
         {
             cellsInTable.style.backgroundcolor ="yellow"
         }

    }
        var gradeAverage =0

      gradeAverage = sum/5;

      if(gradeAverage >= 0 && gradeAverage <40)
      {
        cellsInTable.item(7).style.backgroundColor = "red";
        cellsInTable.item(7).style.color ="white";
        console.log(cellsInTable)
      }


      cellsInTable.item(7).innerHTML = Math.round(gradeAverage) + "%";

  }
}
```

Also, the HTML to go with it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Student Assignment Grades </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Table.css">
        <script src="getAverageFunction.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Student Assignment Grades </h1>
        <table id="gradesTable" class="gradesTable" contenteditable>
            <caption> <STRONG>Student Grades </STRONG> </caption>
            <tr>
                <th id="StudentNames" contenteditable="false">Student Names</th>
                <th id="StudentID" contenteditable="false"> Student ID</th>
                <th id="StudentResults" contenteditable="false"> Assignment 1</th>
                <th id="StudentResults" contenteditable="false"> Assignment 2</th>
                    <th id="StudentResults" contenteditable="false"> Assignment 3</th>
                    <th id="StudentResults" contenteditable="false"> Assignment 4</th>
                    <th id="StudentResults" contenteditable="false"> Assignment 5</th>
                <th id="Average" contenteditable="false"> Final Grade</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>          
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>          
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
                <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <!-- button to invoke the calculateAverage Function, styled with a coloured background -->

        <button class="btnCenter" onclick="getAverage()"> Calculate Final Grades</button>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to make sure you are aware, you could do this using CSS. By adding a classname (like 'unsubmitted') to the td field, and then configure your unsubmitted style to style your  td (including background and the dash(-)) with pure css. This has the advantage that you can then change the style in one place in your css file or &lt;style> tag which is safer and ubiquitous across the page

Comment: But would I be able to do that with contenteditable?

Comment: contenteditable isn't really applicable here

Answer (score 0):

See the bottom of the JavaScript for comments.

```js
// Get a reference to the table just once and name variables with camelCase
var table = document.getElementById('gradesTable');

// Get reference to the button and assign the click event handler
document.querySelector(".btnCenter").addEventListener("click", getAverage);

function getAverage(){     
  // No need for counter loop. Loop over the rows array directly
  let rows = Array.prototype.slice.call(table.rows);
  rows.forEach(function(row){
  
    // Get all the Assignment cells into an array
    let cells = Array.prototype.slice.call(row.querySelectorAll(".Assignment"));
  
    // Using let and defining these in the row loop keeps the values unique for the row
    let sum = 0;
    let gradeAverage = 0;
  
    // Now just loop the cells Array
    cells.forEach(function(cell,index){
         
      // Don't use .innerHTML for strings that don't contain any HTML
      // It's wasteful and has security implications. Use .textContent instead
      var currentValue = parseInt(cell.textContent);
      if(currentValue >= 0 && currentValue <=100){
        sum += currentValue;     
      }
          
      // If the cell has "-" for content
      if(cell.textContent === '"-"'){
        // Apply a pre-made CSS class
        cell.classList.add("noGrade");
      } else {
        // Remove a pre-made CSS class
        cell.classList.remove("noGrade");
      }  
      
      // If this is the last cell in the row
      if(index === cells.length-1){
        gradeAverage = sum/5;
        cell.nextElementSibling.textContent = Math.round(gradeAverage) + "%";
        
        // There is a grade, so check it for low
        if(gradeAverage >= 0 && gradeAverage < 40) {
          cell.nextElementSibling.classList.add("lowGrade");
        } else {
          cell.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("lowGrade");
        }
      }
          
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.noGrade {background-color:yellow;}
.lowGrade { background-color:red; color:white; }
```

```html
<h1> Student Assignment Grades </h1>
<table id="gradesTable" class="gradesTable" contenteditable>
<caption> <STRONG>Student Grades </STRONG> </caption>
 <tr>
  <th id="StudentNames" contenteditable="false">Student Names</th>
  <th id="StudentID" contenteditable="false"> Student ID</th>
  <th id="StudentResults" contenteditable="false"> Assignment 1</th>
  <th id="StudentResults" contenteditable="false"> Assignment 2</th>
    <th id="StudentResults" contenteditable="false"> Assignment 3</th>
    <th id="StudentResults" contenteditable="false"> Assignment 4</th>
  <th id="StudentResults" contenteditable="false"> Assignment 5</th>
  <th id="Average" contenteditable="false"> Final Grade</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>   
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>   
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
  <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
 </tr>
</table>
    
<!-- Don't set up events with inline HTML event attributes like onclick.
     Separate your JavaScript from your HTML and do that work in JavaScript -->
<button class="btnCenter"> Calculate Final Grades</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, is there  a way of doing this without jquerey? Cause I’m not allowed use that for my assignment

Comment: @Darragh.H There wasn't any JQuery in this in the first place. I've also reworked this to show you proper techniques. Read the HTML and JavaScript comments.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I seen query selector and thought it was  and also what do you mean by not setting up with inline html events like onclick? Sorry I’m very new to html and js so I’m still wrapping my head around the vocabulary

Comment: Look at the way you set up the button.. In the HTML, you have `onclick="getAverage()"`. Now, look at how I did it. There isn't anything about `click` in the HTML. It's all in the JavaScript, which is how it should be. And, if you are being taught to do it that way, you need to ask for your money back. I'm serious. I've been teaching this stuff for 25 years and I can tell you that most courses are taught by people who don't really understand modern standards and the implications of what they are doing.

Comment: Oh ok yeah I see that, and this is gonna sound stupid, but the reason I had on click was because we needed to have a button that when clicked it done the getAverage function, so by it being in the JavaScript it’ll work the same way?, yeah we aren’t being thought, we were told to go learn html, css and JavaScript off w3Schools by our web information processing lecturer.

Comment: @Darragh.H FYI: W3 Schools is well-known **not** to be a resource to ever use. They often have inaccurate, incomplete, or flat out wrong information. In fact, that site is the #1 reason that new self-taught developers continue the bad practice of inline HTML event attributes like `onclick` in the first place. They are promoting 20+ year old syntax that has many different reasons why it should not be used. So, if someone is telling you to learn from that site, it tells me that they don't understand what they are saying.

Comment: Do all your research at the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn). Long story short, Netscape invented JavaScript. When Netscape went out of business, the Mozilla Foundation became the "stewards" of the JavaScript language. Mozilla makes FireFox. They (along with the [World Wide Web Consortium](https://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/)) are the authorities on this stuff.

Comment: Can I just ask, in the if statement and else statement you have classList.add and .Remove(“noGrade”) but I don’t have noGrade Id, class or variable. Is that ok?

Comment: The class is defined in the CSS. The JavaScript adds and removes it dynamically as needed.

Comment: Anyway you could show me a general basic beginners version of this, like it’s my first JavaScript assignment with not knowing enough of the language for this, I’m sorry but I’m only starting and having a hard time figuring things out

Comment: I understand, but this really is pretty basic and I've documented what each step of the code does in the comments. Is there a specific question you have?

Comment: What does the nextElementSibling part do? And also just another question how to I adapt it to say if I’ve a button to add rows and add columns, just couldn’t actually figure it out how to adapt it

Comment: `nextElementSibling` is used to navigate from the node that it is called on to the next sibling element that follows it. And, if you added buttons to add/remove rows, you wouldn't change anything in my code. That's the point of why my solution is a good one - it doesn't rely on `id`s. It's works based on the relative location of the nodes.

Comment: Oh ok I kinda of understand that, I’d need to go and research it, and so even the gradAverage= sum/5 that wouldn’t change it all

Comment: No it wouldn’t unless you were to add another colum. Then, you’d just change that to 6.

Comment: Ok thanks, any idea how you would use cookies to save the structure of the table and it’s details, so for example if it had5 rows and 6 columns

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```js
const targetStr = '"-"';

function colorCells() {
  var a = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('td'));
  a.forEach(td => {
    if (td.textContent === targetStr) {
      td.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    }
  });
}

function getAverage() {
  return;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', colorCells);
```

```html
<head>
  <title> Student Assignment Grades </title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Student Assignment Grades </h1>
  <table id="gradesTable" class="gradesTable" contenteditable>
    <caption>
      <STRONG>Student Grades </STRONG> </caption>
    <tr>
      <th id="StudentNames" contenteditable="false">Student Names</th>
      <th id="StudentID" contenteditable="false"> Student ID</th>
      <th id="StudentResults" contenteditable="false"> Assignment 1</th>
      <th id="StudentResults" contenteditable="false"> Assignment 2</th>
      <th id="StudentResults" contenteditable="false"> Assignment 3</th>
      <th id="StudentResults" contenteditable="false"> Assignment 4</th>
      <th id="StudentResults" contenteditable="false"> Assignment 5</th>
      <th id="Average" contenteditable="false"> Final Grade</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable class="StudentName">"Your Name"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="StudentID">"Your Student Number"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable class="Assignment">"-"</td>
      <td contenteditable="false" class="Final Grade"> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <!-- button to invoke the calculateAverage Function, styled with a coloured background -->

  <button class="btnCenter" onclick="getAverage()"> Calculate Final Grades</button>


</body>
```